# Under EASA regulations can I log PIC hours on exercises for a rating already completed?

Tags: commercial-aviation, flight-training, easa-regulations, cpl, pic

The scenario is this: a zero-to-hero modular CPL program is contracted at School A. Due to delays, the student decides to jump ship and complete the CPL exercises at School B in order to enable him to work on commercial ops before his training is finished at School A.

After receiving the CPL, the student continues training at School A in his free time, since he has already paid for the training.

The question is this: When he gets to the CPL exercises, what are the rules for logging time? In principle, can they be logged as PIC time, since the student is already in possession of a CPL, even though from School A’s perspective and according to their syllabus, the exercises must be flown as Dual?

To clarify, this is training done in Europe, under EASA rules.

Comment: If you don't need the dual training for a rating why wouldn't you apply the pre-paid credits towards flight time instead of paying for a CFI you don't need?

Comment: @Michael Hall, because the school refuses to modify anything. They won’t even consider ratings completed at other ATOs within the context of their syllabus

Answer (score 1):

My reading is that this is between you and the school.

[Part-FCL](https://www.easa.europa.eu/sites/default/files/dfu/Part-FCL.pdf) describes the rules for logging PIC time in FCL.050(b)(1):

> (i) the holder of a licence may log as PIC time all of the flight time
> during which he or she is the PIC;

It's between you and the instructor who the PIC is.

> (ii) the applicant for or the holder of a pilot licence may log as PIC time all solo flight time, flight time as SPIC and flight time under
> supervision provided that such SPIC time and flight time under
> supervision are countersigned by the instructor;

Student Pilot in Command (SPIC) is defined as "a student pilot acting as pilot-in-command on a flight with
an instructor where the latter will only observe the student pilot and shall not influence or control
the flight of the aircraft." If the instructor is content just to observe, you are acting as SPIC and can log PIC time (though the instructor needs to agree to countersign it).

The next four paragraphs are not relevant to your situation.

So you can log the time if the school consents to designate you as PIC (unlikely) or the instructor agrees to sign off on SPIC time.

On the other hand, I've heard anecdotally that different competent authorities have different ideas about what should be logged. It's worth checking with your own before logging time you're not sure about.